# How authenticate against LDAP in HTML

Tags: html, ldap

I am not expert with html. I found in the web a simple authentication form. My question is where I put my authenticate server. when the user name and password has been verified, i would like to open to other index.html

> LDAP configuration: 
>   LDAP Registry Location - ldap://pages.sysaid.com:389

```
              <!DOCTYPE html>
              <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
              <!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
              <!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
              <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
              <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
              <title>Login Form</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
              <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
              </head>
              <body>
              <section class="container">
              <div class="login">
                <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
               <form method="post" action="index.html">
              <p><input type="text" name="login" value=""      placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
             <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p class="remember_me">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
        Remember me on this computer
      </label>
    </p>
       <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
       </form>
       </div>

       <div class="login-help">
      <p>Forgot your password? <a href="index.html">Click here to reset it</a>.</p>
   </div>
   </section>

      <section class="about">
     <p class="about-links">
     <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/login-form" target="_parent">View Article</a>
     <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/login-form.zip" target="_parent">Download</a>
    </p>
    <p class="about-author">
     &copy; 2012&ndash;2013 <a href="http://thibaut.me" target="_blank">Thibaut Courouble</a> -
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/mit-license" target="_blank">MIT License</a><br>
    Original PSD by <a href="http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/clean-simple-login-form-psd/" target="_blank">Orman Clark</a>
  </section>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with html at all.
Usually the web server you use provides different types of authentication mechanism.

If you tell us what kind of web server you use, we can help you

Comment: Hi , i am useing Redhat httpd  ( Apache server )

Comment: you will need to configure 2 modules:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html  and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ldap.html  . the setup is very easy. you should use an ldap group where your account is in. if you need help to find out DN-roots I suggest you to download JXplorer. You can find all needed information like DN-root, CN-names there.